# How to show suggestions for search

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, jsp

I am trying to add suggestions to my search box. Once user enters something it should show the suggestions and if user hover on any of the suggestion it should be highlighted and when the suggestion is clicked it should be added to search terms along with a semicolon to separate the search terms.

I am able to show the suggestions but the problem is implementing the following

**Expected result is as following**

```
Search box >>> f
suggestions first 
            four
when first is clicked it will be highlighted then
Search box >>> first;

when t is clicked 
Search box >>> first;t
suggestions two 
            three
click on three will cause to remove the t from search box and add the three
Search box >>> first;three

when tw is entered
Search box >>> first;three;tw
suggestions two 
            twelve
when two is selected 
Search box (first;three;two
```

**suggestion.jsp**

```
<c:forEach items="${sug}" var="mysug">
    <label id="suggestion" onclick="selectSug(<c:out value="${mysug}"/>)"><c:out 
    value="${mysug}"/></label>
    <br/>
</c:forEach>
```

**search.jsp**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function selectSug(value){
         alert("vlue"+value);
         var temp = document.getElementById("mysearch").textContent ;
         document.getElementById("mysearch").textContent = temp + value + " ; ";
  }

  function findsug(value){
              if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                {
                    document.getElementById("sugs").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                } 
            }
            xmlhttp.open("get","search?input="+value,false);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
   ...
<s:textfield id="mysearch" name="mysearch" label="Search"        
                         onkeyup="findsug(this.value)"/>

<div id="sugs">
  </div>
```

**mystyle.css**

```
#suggestion:hover{
    background:red;
}
```

**Let me know if I should include any other part of the code.**
  I am also wondering if I can do it in an easier way using jQuery

Comment: Try using this http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: I'm not getting how you are implementing it as you are using ajax to get search result and in the example you are using JSTL.. Anyways you can use the CHOSEN library and is quiet easy to use.

Comment: @Meherzad, that part of code is in suggestion.jsp page, ajax is used to load that and embed it into the search.jsp page.

Comment: How you are embedding it?

Comment: using  if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                    {
                        document.getElementById("sugs").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }

Comment: @Meherzad Ive just added that part of code to the question.

Comment: Cool.. Try chosen, i have used it for similar problem which you are facing. Post if you have any doubts using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try jquery-ui given widget

[auto complete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)